# Table chart options in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

This [example code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fe93e7e373f8990aecee7aca3d3ef201) below is generated using [GEE Data Table Charts Section](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_datatable).

How can I print all table rows (they go to display in two pages) in one page and numbers in the second column with two decimal places?

```
// Define a DataTable using a JavaScript array with a column property header.
var dataTable = [
  [
    {label: 'State', role: 'domain', type: 'string'},
    {label: 'Population', role: 'data', type: 'number'},
  ],
  ['CA', 37253.956],
  ['NY', 19378.102],
  ['IL', 12830],
  ['MI', 9883],
  ['OR', 3831.234],
  ['CA', 37253.956],
  ['NY', 19378.102],
  ['IL', 12830],
  ['MI', 9883],
  ['OR', 3831.234],
  ['CA', 37253.956],
  ['NY', 19378.102],
  ['IL', 12830],
  ['MI', 9883],
  ['OR', 3831.234]
];

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart = ui.Chart(dataTable).setChartType('Table').setOptions({
  format : '#.###',
  title: 'State Population (US census, 2010)',
  legend: {position: 'none'},
  colors: ['1d6b99'],
  page:'disable'
});
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `allowHtml` as true and then you can use all the css [configurations](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#configuration-options).

```
var chart = ui.Chart(dataTable).setChartType('Table').setOptions({
  format : '#.###',
  title: 'State Population (US census, 2010)',
  legend: {position: 'none'},
  colors: ['1d6b99'],
  page:'disable',
  allowHtml: true,
  pageSize:20
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rahul...

Comment: Dear Rahul, how about the format of numbers, when i set the format as #.##, there is error in displaying numbers, it is displayed like  ###.##